# What is the JDO equivalent of datastore's query.setAncestor(Key key)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have been looking everywhere trying to figure out what the JDO equivalent of Google App Engine's low-level API function: `.setAncestor(Key key)` is.  I have not been able to find this anywhere!  I've read that this type of behavior is not supported in native JDO.  Is this true?  I can't do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is supported natively, however you can use a query:

```
pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM MyElement WHERE myParent == :parent");
```

Note that is a little different, though, as the low-level API setAncestor will search *all* descendants.  And you have to establish the one-to-one or one-to-many relationship via JDO.

See:  http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/b07c62030e7bbcb8